# Simple extension method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create an extension method for class but seems something is wrong. Below is the code, the output JS-file is correct but the compiler twice times shows an error **"test.ts(10,16): The property 'close' does not exist on value of type 'Test'"**
What should be corrected ?

```
class Test {
} 

interface Test
{
    close():any;
}

Test.prototype.close  = function() {}

var t = new Test();

t.close();
```

**Update**: The code above is compiled okay with built-in types. I need to extend my own classes.

**Update 2**: Old compiler version issue. Currently all is okay!

Comment: There is the code that emulates such thing: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398391

Answer (score 5):

This example uses inheritance to extend the original object. The naming is just for illustration.

```
class Test {
    baseMethod() {

    }
} 

class TestWithClose extends Test {
    close() {

    }
}

var t = new TestWithClose();

t.close();
t.baseMethod();
```

**Update**

You have mentioned in your comment that you can write extension methods for built-in functions in the way you want and I can see that you want to do the same for your own code, but that isn't possible.

I hope this explains why.

When you create a declaration in TypeScript, you can extend that declaration by adding to it. You can either use the declare keyword or place the file in a `.d.ts` file:

For example, if you have this declaration in one file:

```
declare interface ExampleInterface {
    methodOne();
}
```

You can extend the declaration in another file:

```
declare interface ExampleInterface {
    methodTwo();
}
```

So when you use it, you have both functions available:

```
function example(example: ExampleInterface) {
    example.methodOne();
    example.methodTwo();
}
```

These aren't really extension methods - this is just telling the compiler about an implementation in more than one go. This is particularly useful for jQuery as it allows each plugin to have a definition that adds to the `JQuery` interface.

You can't do this for you own TypeScript code, because adding to an interface will cause all implementations to require an update to match the interface definition.

The mind-shift here is that TypeScript is giving you static typing and you are looking for dynamic behaviour - so you have to choose one or the other. For example, you can just use dynamic behaviour where you really want it and leave the rest statically typed:

```
class Test {
} 

// statically typed

var stTest = new Test();

// dynamically typed

var testExtender: any = Test;
testExtender.prototype.close = function() {
    alert('Close');
};

var t: any = new Test();
t.close();
```

That isn't to say something won't be added to the language in the future to support extension methods.

Comment: This is not what I asked for. If I extend i.e. Array, I will be able to call new metod via Array instance:     `myArrayInstance.newArrayMethod(1,2,3)

Comment: The first variant is a disaster. It just unmaintainable code, I'd better stay with JS.

Comment: @MadHollander I have added further explanations to my answer. I also have a better suggestion than my original first example - so I have removed it.

Comment: "The mind-shift here is that TypeScript is giving you static typing and you are looking for dynamic behaviour" - Not completely true, typescript also introduces some sugar syntax that gets compiled to native JS.

Comment: @Alex the paragraph is concerned with static vs dynamic types. It doesn't suggest that TypeScript *only* gives static typing, but that seems to be how you have interpreted it. It does, in fact, allow both static and dynamic types (and many other features).